# How do i retrieve a string from a HttpResponse object after posting to a PHP-file?

Tags: java, android, post, entity, httpresponse

I wish to retrieve the data sent back by the php-file after using a HTTP-post in android. My code looks like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/post.php");
List <NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "hejsan"));

try{
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
}catch(UnsupportedEncodingException a){
        infoText.setText("failed to post");
}

try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        infoText.setText(response.getEntity().toString());
}catch(ClientProtocolException b){
        infoText.setText("failed to get response");
}catch(IOException e){
        infoText.setText("failed IOEXCEPTION");
}this code only changes the "TextView" to: org.apache.http.conn
```

BasicManagedEntity@45f94a68 ... My PHP-file is a very simple one, it only echos the text "data". I figure the problem has something to do with the "response.getEntity().toString()" but how do I get the sent back data as a string from the HttpPost object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the response handler.. Something like this:

```
public static String getResponseBody(HttpResponse response) {
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHander = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = null;
    try {
        responseBody = (String) responseHander.handleResponse(response);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    logger.debug("Response Body Data:" + responseBody);

    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: What does "logger.debug("Response Body Data:" + responseBody);" my eclipse doesn't seem to know about "logger"... It however works without that row :O

Comment: that would be Log instead of logger, and it would take 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can also use EntityUtils:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```